# How to retrieve the domain of a web archived website using the archived url in Python?

Tags: python, url

Given a url such as :

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20010312011552/www.feralhouse.com/cgi-bin/store/commerce.cgi?page=ac2.html
```

Is there a way (using some library, package, or vanilla Python) to retrieve the domain "www.feralhouse.com"?

I thought of simply using split at "www", split the second-index item at "com", and re-group the first-index item like:

```
url = "http://web.archive.org/web/20010312011552/www.feralhouse.com/cgi-bin/store/commerce.cgi?page=ac2.html"
url1=url.split("www")
url2=url1[1].split("com")
desired_output = "www"+url2[0]+"com"
print(desired_output)
#www.feralhouse.com
```

But there are some exceptions to this method (sites with no www, I assume they rely on the browser automatically changing that). I would prefer a less "hacky" approach if possible. Thanks in advance!

NOTE: I dont want a solution just for this SPECIFIC url, I want a solution for all possible archived urls.

EDIT: Another example url

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20000614170338/http://www.clonejesus.com/
```

Comment: Why don't you split at ``/``?

Comment: @MikeScotty and how would I know which part to get? I want a solution for all possible archived sites, not this specific one.

Comment: do you have an example where that would be an issue? it should always be the 5th element as far as i can tell. otherwise do a regex search for after a 14 digit number

Comment: @Sayse ```http://web.archive.org/web/20000614170338/http://www.clonejesus.com/```

Comment: @Sayse ``cgi-bin`` is specific to that requested site, but splitting at ``/`` should be safe. Or even easier: seems there's always a fixed **length** of characters at the start

Comment: so just get everything after the 14 digit number and then do the usual python way of extracting a domain from a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods, one with split, one with `re` module:

```
s = 'http://web.archive.org/web/20010312011552/www.feralhouse.com/cgi-bin/store/commerce.cgi?page=ac2.html'

print(s.split('/', 5)[-1])

import re

print(re.findall(r'\d{14}/(.*)', s)[0])
```

Prints:

```
www.feralhouse.com/cgi-bin/store/commerce.cgi?page=ac2.html
www.feralhouse.com/cgi-bin/store/commerce.cgi?page=ac2.html
```

Comment: Ill use the first since there is less things to import. Thank you!